# Apache as ReverseProxy with authentication OAuth2.0 and check

Tags: php, apache, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, reverse-proxy

I configured Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7 as reverse proxy with authentication OAuth 2.0 with google.
this is my **http.conf** file:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyTimeout 300

<VirtualHost test.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName test.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https://test.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test.mydomain.com:443>
    ServerName test.mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test_error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test_access.log combined

    OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
    OIDCClientID xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
    OIDCClientSecret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    OIDCRedirectURI https://test.mydomain.com/index.php
    OIDCScope "profile openid"
    OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003
    OIDCCookiePath /
    OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User
    OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
    OIDCClaimPrefix example_

    <Location />
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1:5563/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1:5563/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I digit https://test.mydomain.com I redirect to google authentication and after (if the login is ok) to the reverse resource on http://192.168.1.1:5563/

Now I'm trying to create a custom login page in PHP, because I would check if the user can access (because with Google OAuth all member of domain can access) or not to this remote resource http://192.168.1.1:5563/ and I created my **index.php** page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config/config.php');
$login_button = '';

//This $_GET["code"] variable value received after user has login into their Google Account redirct to PHP script then this variable value has been received
if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{
// ... set session variable ...
}

//This is for check user has login into system by using Google account, if User not login into system then it will execute if block of code and make code for display Login link for Login using Google account.
if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
 //Create a URL to obtain user authorization
$login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'"><img src="images/sign-in-with-google.png" /></a>';
$_SESSION['logged'] = false;
 }
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Log in/Sign up screen</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container"> 
   <div class="frame">
    <div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
        <h1><img align="center" src="images/logo_rouded.png" width="100" height="auto"></h1>
     <?php
            if($login_button == '')
            {
                echo "<form class=\"form-signin\" action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\"form\">";
                echo "<p align=\"center\">Select your enviroment</p>";

                echo "<div class=\"btn-animateOscar\">";
                echo "<a class=\"btn-signin\" onclick=\"window.open('test.php','popUpWindow','height=650,width=1000,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')\">test</a>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class=\"btn-animate_signout\">";
                echo "<a class=\"btn-signin\" href=\"logout.php\">Sign out</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</form>";
            } else {
                echo "<p align=\"center\">Sign in with Activo Account</p>";
                echo '<div align="center">'.$login_button . '</div>';
            }
            ?>     
          </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And **test.php** that I call with href is:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>TEST</title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
 </head>
 <body> 
         <?php    
                if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged']==true){
                    echo "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://test.mydomain.com/TEST\"></iframe>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
                        echo "<div class=\"frame\">";
                            echo "<div ng-app ng-init=\"checked = false\">";
                                echo "<h1><img align=\"center\" src=\"images/logo_rouded.png\" width=\"100\" height=\"auto\"></h1>";
                                    echo "<form class=\"form-signin\" action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\"form\">";
                                        echo "<p align=\"center\">You are not login, please login</p>"; 
                                        echo "<p align=\"center\">You'll redirect to login page in 5 seconds</p>";
                                        header('Refresh: 5; url=index.php');
                                    echo "</form>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }    
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I changed my **http.conf** as below:

```
<VirtualHost test.mydomain.com:443>
        ServerName test.mydomain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/googleaccess/
        DirectoryIndex index.php

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /TEST http://192.168.1.1:5563/ts/ts2/index.html
ProxyPassReverse /TEST http://192.168.1.1:5563/ts/ts2/index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Now the problem is:
1) the reverse proxy doesn't work correctly (I think that is a bad configuration in http.conf)
2) If I digit https://test.mydomain.com/TEST I jump the google authentication, how can I block this?
3) I can't enable the traffic form all network to http://192.168.1.1:5563/ts/ts2/index.html, for this reason I must use a reverse proxy.

Thanks for the help